# Prevent unchanged POST requests be sent

Tags: http, post

I'm looking for a way to prevent unchanged POST request to be sent.
I know I can just gray out the "Send" button as soon as it gets pressed once, but I was looking for a way, maybe a HTTP Header, that will merely ignore the request if it doesn't have any changed field.

Comment: You could add a parameter to your request (a flag) and in your webservice handle the request based upon the flag.  If the flag is set don't execute code if it is not set execute code.

Comment: have you tried the [Post-Redirect-Get pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)?

Comment: Have a look at [HTTP ETags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the .serialize() method from jQuery for save the last submit and compare this value with the new value.

Something like this:

```
var lastSubmit;
$( "#myForm" ).submit(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var newSubmit=( $( this ).serialize() );
    if (lastSubmit==newSubmit) {
         alert("Don't submit")
    } else {
        alert("Submit")
        lastSubmit=newSubmit;
    }

});
```

I wrote this jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/uxjynnhj/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a copy of the last request on the client, and compare new request with it. If they are the same, do nothing. It could be in a javascript object, or even in local storage or cookie if you want it to survive page refresh.